# panicked at 'Bad input data provided to query_info: Codec error' when running a dev node

Tags: substrate-node-template

I get an error when running dev node and transfer coin to test address.

I use: https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-front-end-template

Here are the console logs:

````
2023-05-08 07:55:45   Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x1d62fc09c822d0857cd502b551b6552f1da4ff364e23340dc78544845ed8a70b    
2023-05-08 07:55:45   Prepared block for proposing at 230 [hash: 0x80339fd8bbeb7bfa0aaa05ae378dc2c0a279d75b082590ef0c167f58f282033c; parent_hash: 0x1d62…a70b; extrinsics (1): [0xd9b2…9334]]    
2023-05-08 07:55:45   Pre-sealed block for proposal at 230. Hash now 0x045ed0fb58b8bcf39f27532d75e2d9a7e403c888da811947612589686b6f1a86, previously 0x80339fd8bbeb7bfa0aaa05ae378dc2c0a279d75b082590ef0c167f58f282033c.    
2023-05-08 07:55:45  ✨ Imported #230 (0x045e…1a86)    
2023-05-08 07:55:46   Idle (0 peers), best: #230 (0x045e…1a86), finalized #227 (0x906b…bba2), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0    
2023-05-08 07:55:47  panicked at 'Bad input data provided to query_info: Codec error', /opt/spacex/runtime/src/lib.rs:902:1    
2023-05-08 07:55:47  Unknown error: Client(Execution(Other("Wasm execution trapped: wasm trap: unreachable
wasm backtrace:
    0: 0x2156 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0x1ea3 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h125c8438143be5c3
    2: 0x1319ea - <unknown>!TransactionPaymentApi_query_info
note: run with `WASMTIME_BACKTRACE_DETAILS=1` environment variable to display more information
")))    
2023-05-08 07:55:48   Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x045ed0fb58b8bcf39f27532d75e2d9a7e403c888da811947612589686b6f1a86    
2023-05-08 07:55:48   Prepared block for proposing at 231 [hash: 0x04084edcacd1ba011cd8a6a3b52871ab8b0067eab1cf57c1712bc6c6b94d8e9a; parent_hash: 0x045e…1a86; extrinsics (1): [0x2139…b8c3]]    
2023-05-08 07:55:48   Pre-sealed block for proposal at 231. Hash now 0x6ac10d2fcf6e2e63eb18507cb42b9eee7df73e05f1f6c6a2e429d462f0e339dc, previously 0x04084edcacd1ba011cd8a6a3b52871ab8b0067eab1cf57c1712bc6c6b94d8e9a.    
2023-05-08 07:55:48  ✨ Imported #231 (0x6ac1…39dc)```
````

Comment: Check the steps on this tutorial: https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/build-local-blockchain/

Answer (score 0):

@china_zhangsan which version of explorer you are using. Try to switch to the older version of explorer and re-run the node by using the command :- ./target/release/"binary_name" --dev --tmp
May be this will help you